# Share information between two load-balanced IIS servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, load-balancing, web-farm

I've two load-balanced IIS servers, and I need to share some information between them.

The information is not related to the user session, so I don't see how a session state provider could help here.

I cannot use the database (requirement), and apparently use shared files for synchronization is [not good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697647/locking-behaviour-is-different-via-network-shares).

What may I use? Of course keeping it as simple as possible, I know I could run memcache or something fancy, but the only thing I need is create a unique number for both servers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) service that they both have access to would be a suitable solution.

Why can't you use a database?  (that is the more standard way)

**Edit** - if all you need is a unique value (notice I say value and not "number") then I would use a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) - the chance of a collision is [so small it's ridiculous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184869/are-guid-collisions-possible) and it means that you can avoid introducing an additional dependency.

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Job done :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that as well. It has to be a unique number, but shared in both servers, that is, both have to use the same unique number.

Comment: If they need to be the same, a database really is the most sensible choice... transactional, high performance and well documented... why can't you use a database?